# More appropriate expression for “B is half-of-A greater than A.”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Let **A** and **B** be whole numbers such that `B = A + A ÷ 2`.

Assuming I need to express it as `greater than`, I could say:

> **B** is *half-of-**A*** greater than **A**.

But I want to get rid of the hyphens. I want to know the alternative way to express *how much* one is greater than another one, in one complete sentence. How do I do it?

Also how do I express B = A + C ÷ 2 with greater than and no hyphens, in a natural way if possible?

Comment: B equals A plus one half of A. B=A + 1/2 B

Comment: It's not quite "greater than", but you can say "B is half again as great as A."

Comment: @CanadianYankee `half again` is new one to me. Thank you. I know that it's not an inequality, but I wanted to emphasize how much the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural way to express this is to use percentages.

> B is 50% greater than A

There are alternatives

> B is 1½ times A
>
> B is 150% of A

To say B = A + C/2 you could say

> B is 50% of C greater than A

although at some point it becomes simpler just to read the mathematical expression:

> B equals A plus C over two.

Comment: May I ask you one more question: how do I express `B = A + C ÷ 2` with `greater than` and no hyphens, in a _natural_ way if possible?

Comment: I've copied your supplementary question to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The  idiom you could use in this case is [half again as](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/half+again+as).  So you would say:

> B is half again as large as A.